# how to roundoff the date field to end of the month in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have requirement to roundoff the month to end of the month with additional 2 months.

Example: Start Date: 15-01-2022

End date shoule be:  31-03-2022

I tried the below code to add the 2 months

```
var startDate=new Date("15-01-2022");
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+ 60);
        this.exitEffectDate = startDate;
        console.log( this.exitEffectDate); // 16-03-2022
```

How can I round off the value to end of the month in JS?

Comment: Easiest, set to first of next month then subtract one day.

Comment: If you are willing to use Apex it's quite simple. Something similar to [this approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/140131/2995).

Comment: @Phil could you please elaborate more, with the sample code if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript will automatically bump dates less than 1 to the prior months, as appropriate, just as it will go to future months with large positive numbers.

```
var startDate=new Date("2022-01-15"); // Use ISO8601 format!
startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth()+3); // Forward three months
startDate.setDate(0); // 0 is the last day of the previous month 
this.exitEffectDate = startDate;
console.log( this.exitEffectDate); // 2022-03-31
```

This isn't LWC specific, it's a natural feature of JavaScript.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you